# Filter dataframe rows based on return value of foo() applied to first column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have the following dataframe

```
     Path              Latency   Noise         SNR
1                A->B  0.001769  3.535534e-07  34.515450
2          A->C->D->B  0.006240  1.247207e-06  29.040613
3    A->C->D->E->F->B  0.011315  2.261351e-06  26.456319
4       A->C->D->F->B  0.008269  1.652609e-06  27.818298
5       A->C->E->D->B  0.008111  1.620994e-06  27.902185
..                ...       ...           ...        ...
346     F->D->A->C->E  0.008002  1.599196e-06  27.960983
347  F->D->B->A->C->E  0.009928  1.984271e-06  27.023989
348        F->D->C->E  0.005527  1.104621e-06  29.567867
349           F->D->E  0.003859  7.713011e-07  31.127760
350              F->E  0.003094  6.184658e-07  32.086843
```

I have a method taking an input string and returning a bool(**this is a simplified version**, not the actual method):

```
def foo(str: str) -> bool:
    if str[0] == 'A': return False
    return True
```

I want to filter the dataframe keeping the rows whoose path if passed to foo() return True. **I cannot modify foo()**, how can I do it?

**Expected Output**

```
     Path              Latency   Noise         SNR
..                ...       ...           ...        ...
346     F->D->A->C->E  0.008002  1.599196e-06  27.960983
347  F->D->B->A->C->E  0.009928  1.984271e-06  27.023989
348        F->D->C->E  0.005527  1.104621e-06  29.567867
349           F->D->E  0.003859  7.713011e-07  31.127760
350              F->E  0.003094  6.184658e-07  32.086843
```

Comment: can you also put your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR**

```
mask = df.apply(lambda row: foo(row['Path']), axis=1)
res: pd.DataFrame = df[mask]
```

**Solution**

To filter the rows of a DataFrame according to the return value of `foo(str: str) -> bool` applied to the values contained in column `Path` of each row **the solution is to generate a mask** with [pandas.DataFrame.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

**How does a mask work?**

The mask works as follow: given a dataframe `df: pd.DataFrame` and a `mask: pd.Series<bool>` accessing with square brackets `df[mask]` will result in a new DataFrame with only the rows corresponnding to a `True` value of the mask series.

**How to get the mask**

Since `df.apply(fuction, axis, ...)` takes as input a function one would be tempted to pass `foo()` as argument of the `apply()` but **this is wrong**.
The function argumennt of apply() must be a function taking as argument a pd.Series and not a string therefore the correct way to get the mask is the following, where `axis = 1` indicates that we're applyinng the lambda to get the boolean value to every row of the dataframe rather than to every column.

```
mask = df.apply(lambda row: foo(row['Path']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
mask = df.apply(filter_fn, axis=1)
df = df[mask]
```

should work fine. `filter_fn` should return `bool` values.

Comment: I'm testing it rn, axis = 1 selects the 'Path' column right?

Comment: No, axis=1 will make it a row-wise operation.

Comment: The post you copied and pasted this solution from is about a different question, since filter_fn takes as input a row

Comment: Oh, your function expects the 'Path' as input? If yes, change the first line to: df.Path.apply(filter_fn)

Comment: It doesn't work. I found an answer myself, check it out